# Can Azure Programmatically Notify Upon Completion of a SQL Database Deployment?

Tags: azure

I'm programmatically-creating Azure SQL databases. This is done asynchronously and so I need some way of knowing when the deployment is complete so that I can execute some post-deployment code.

Ideally, I'd like an Azure Function to get triggered when Azure signals that the deployment of the resource is done. In other words, an event-based notification. Is there a way to do this?

All I have found is GetDeployment REST method that I would have to poll periodically to determine when the deployment is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine ARM templates and VSTS webhooks for that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-ci-in-vsts?toc=%2fazure%2fazure-resource-manager%2ftoc.json

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/events#build.complete

Comment: Sorry, not a VSTS deployment. A deployment of an Azure resource (in this case a SQL Database) that is triggered programmatically using Azure SDK. I'll update my question to be clear.